# se pueden usar los botones de el plugin Datatable en un proyecto mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

mi duda es la siguiente, estoy usando el plugin de datatables en mi proyecto, pero cuando voy a usar sus botones para exportar ( quiero exportar a excel ), no me aparecen en mi vista, tengo claro que se puede hacer usando una función para crear el archivo, pero quería lo que ya tengo en el plugin, este es el código que estoy usando de la vista, lo pongo para saber si tengo algún error, no agregué los scripts en el bundle porque quería ver si funcionaban los botones para luego poner todo en orden.

vista

```
@model IEnumerable<Inventario.Models.PiezaConInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inventario";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dataTables")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


<div class="row espacio"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary list-panel" id="list-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading list-panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title list-panel-title">Inventario</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="piezas-data-table"
                       class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                       style="width:100%">
                    <div class=" panel-title" align="right">
                        <a class="btn btn-default boton" href="@Url.Action("CrearExcel","Piezas")">Exportar</a> <!--con este botón es que tengo pensado hacer la función para crear mi excel-->
                    </div>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Coódigo</th>
                            <th>Cantidad</th>
                            <th>Costo</th>
                            <th>Unidad de medida</th>
                            <th>Nueva entrada</th>
                            <th>Nueva Salida</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var pieza in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@pieza.Nombre_pieza</td>
                                <td>@pieza.Codigo_pieza</td>
                                <td>@pieza.Cantidad_pieza</td>
                                <td>@pieza.Costo_pieza</td>
                                <td>@pieza.Unidad_medida</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action( "EntradaPieza","Entradas", new { Id_Pieza = pieza.Id_pieza })">Entrada</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("SalidaPieza","Salidas", new { Id_Pieza = pieza.Id_pieza })">Salida</a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    @section Scripts
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#piezas-data-table').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
                ],
                language: {
                    "decimal": "",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
                    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
                    "infoPostFix": "",
                    "thousands": ",",
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primero",
                        "last": "Ultimo",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>

}
```

bundles, estos los coloco en el archivo bundle que esta en la carpeta app_start y uso el render en la vista layout para solo llamarlos una vez todos los js y css.

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatables").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js", "~/Scripts/DataTables/buttons.bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datatables").Include(
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css", "~/Content/DataTables/css/buttons.bootstrap.css"));
```

así se ve cuando ejecuto el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Agregaste los archivos css y js de datatables? Ten en cuenta que los botones tienen otros archivos js adicionales

Comment: dices en el bundle? si, los agregué y el resultado es el mismo

Comment: ¿En la vista, donde llamas al bundle?

Comment: no los había puesto en el cuando hice la pregunta, ahí están.

Comment: Oki, pero aun faltan los archivos js

Comment: ahí coloqué mi bundle, no está todo el archivo, solo puse los del datatable

Comment: lo que digo es que falta esto: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")

Comment: no, el resultado es el mismo al de la foto que coloqué hace rato.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día Juan.
El código está bien, teóricamente puedes usarlo así y no habrá problema.
Te dejo la documentación: https://datatables.net/reference/button/

Pero ¿No es más fácil crear el botón y ponerle un onclick para hacer que exporte tú excel?, podrías intentarlo así; pienso que te queda más fácil, si no espera haber si a alguien se le ocurre una solución mejor.
Suerte con eso, saludos!

Comment: estoy usando esa documentación, por eso mi pregunta, porque no se visualizan y bueno, si , lo de crear el botón ya lo estoy haciendo, solo que me quería ahorrar tiempo con las herramientas que me ofrece el plugin

Comment: La verdad pienso que depende de la tecnología en la que estás creándolo, lo importante no llegar a la forma más fácil, si no a la más efectiva y que aprendas.
Se puede hacer con muchos lenguajes, pero intenta ponerte ése tipo de retos; saludos.